# Setting NSUserDefault crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I'm setting a value in the user defaults and I don't know why it crashes:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[textField text] forKey:@"STRING"];
```

This is fine but

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[textField text] forKey:settingKey];
```

This is not. `settingKey` is the property declared and synthesized in the class I'm using in. In fact, even this line works

```
[textField setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:settingKey]];
```

When simulator crashes it brings me to the Core Foundation Hash (CFHash) which I can't understand:

```
0x1c24756: call 0x1d79a00; symbol stub for: getpid

"Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_1386_BPT, subcode=0x0)"
```

Comment: What is `settingKey`? Is it an NSString, etc.?

Comment: Are you working on multiple threads?

Comment: settingsKey or settingKey ? (your code example shows both)

Comment: It's settingKey, an NSString. Sorry about that. Not that I'm aware of I'm not working with any other threads.

Comment: I don't know how your synthesizing it but if settingKey is a property you should use self.settingKey or something like @synthesize settingKey = _settingKey; then use _settingKey in your code. Otherwise you may be ending up with a null reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here problem is settingKey is `null` value.

```
if you are trying to set null value as an key arguement then it'l happend.
```

Comment: Huh, I tested it and indeed it is null...it definitely shouldn't be though. Thanks!

Comment: @Le Jiacong:welcome dear mate,if this one useful to you then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what type of object your key is, so the crash could be caused by one of two issues:

1. `settingKey` is not an object which can be stored in an NSDictionary. Any keys and their values stored in NSUserDefaults must be an NSString, NSInteger, etc. It cannot be a primitive data type like int or BOOL. More specifically, a key must be an NSString.
2. `settingKey` is **NULL**, has not been allocated, or has been deallocated prematurely then NSUserDefaults will cause a crash. Keys *cannot* be NULL in NSUserDefaults (or NSDictionaries)

Comment: "NSCoding compliant" means that a given class has accessors for certain keys. A key itself doesn't need to be NSCoding compliant -- for evidence of this, look at the [`NSString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) docs -- NSString doesn't conform to NSCoding. You're right that keys need to be objects -- in fact, for NSUserDefaults, keys need to be strings -- but NSCoding isn't the reason for that.

Comment: @Caleb Oops! Thanks for the information - it seems I misunderstood the NSCoding docs. I'll read up on it. Thank you.